# Applying a library to a sub-project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a React-Native App that uses a video player component (`react-native-video`).
I've had to extend this project for Android to include the ability to load assets from an expansion file so this involved including the `android.vending.expansion.zipfile` project in the `/java/com/` folder of the video project.

The video project sits under my main project via the `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':RCTVideo', ':app'
project(':RCTVideo').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')
```

and build.gradle file:

```
compile project(':RCTVideo')
```

I now realise that I will have to add this same functionality to my separate audio component which also sits under my main project in the same way the video component does.

Rather than be re-apply the same project `android.vending.expansion.zipfile` to my audio component, can I just apply it to my main react-native android project and reference it in the sub-project??!

I'm a little baffled.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue, then you can simply create a separate module called **zipfile** that contains the `android.vending.expansion.zipfile` source. Then just include this module in each app or module as needed:

```
compile project(':zipfile')
```